# How to check if there is no output in python subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I use Python 3. This is a part of my script:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["git", "ls-remote", "--heads", "origin", "master"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
line = proc.stdout.readline()
if line != '':
    print("not empty")
    print(line)
else:
    print(empty)
```

I want to check if there is a remote master. If the content of `line` is not empty (= there is a master) it will print "not empty". If there is no master = no output I want to print empty.

But it does not work:

This is the output without python:

```
$ git ls-remote --heads origin xxx (no output)
$ git ls-remote --heads origin master (output)
a5dd03655381fcee94xx4e759ceba7aeb6456   refs/heads/master
```

This is the output when I run the script when master exists:

```
b'a5dd03655381fcee94xx4e759ceba7aeb6456\trefs/heads/master\n'
```

And when master does not exist:

```
b''
```

How can I make this work? It seems the pipe seems to take different signs like `b''` and `\n` and not only the words.

Comment: Just change it to `if line:`, that should work. If you want to remove the linebreak, call `.strip()` on the line.

Comment: @L3viathan is right, and should probably make the comment into an answer. :)

Comment: @L3viathan Thanks! works, you can write it down as an answer.

Comment: @DenCowboy As a side note, [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython) might accomplish what you are triyng to do as-is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting a binary string as output; many programs do internal decoding and present you with the text string, but `subprocess.Popen` is not one of them.

But you can easily decode it yourself:

```
out_bin = b'a5dd03655381fcee94xx4e759ceba7aeb6456\trefs/heads/master\n'
out_txt = out.decode('utf-8')  # Should be `utf-8` encoded
```

And the `\t` and `\n` are tab, and newline characters, that will do the respective formatting when you `print`.

Moreover, all the methods of the text string, works on binary strings too, its just the implementation/presentation that differs.

Also, on your `if line != '':` condition, you need to either explicitly tell that you are matching against a binary string by:

```
if line != b'':
```

Or better as empty strings are falsey in Python, simply do:

```
if not line:
```