# Check if a unix command returns nothing

Tags: python

I am trying to see if myfile returns nothing after a grep from within python, something like this:

```
command="cat my_file.txt | grep 'string_to_find'"

if os.system(command) == '':
   print('nothing found')
```

Comment: The *only* thing you get from `os.system()` is the exit code of the command; any output goes directly to your terminal, bypassing Python completely.  You need to use one of the functions from the `subprocess` module instead.

Comment: Why don't you just _use Python_ to "grep" through the file?

Comment: I suggest to use `grep -q 'string_to_find' my_file.txt` and check its exit code.

Comment: Have you tried popen? `os.popen("cat my_file.txt | grep 'string_to_find'").read()`

Comment: @user56700 that will do it thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if there is no output in python subprocess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48813957/how-to-check-if-there-is-no-output-in-python-subprocess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting comment to answer:

```
command="cat my_file.txt | grep 'string_to_find'"

if os.popen(command).read() == '':
   print('nothing found')
```

[Documentation for os.popen()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen)

Answer (score 0):

Grep's exit code is 0 if a match was found and 1 if no match was found. (Errors, for example in the regular expression, produce exit code 2). On Posix systems (including Linux), `os.system` returns 256 times the exit code if the command ran to completion, or the number of the signal which terminated the command if it was killed by a signal. (I think it's different on Windows. Consult the Python docs if that matters to you.)

So a crude solution would be:

```py
if os.system("grep 'string to find' 'my_file.txt'") == 256:
    # Nothing found

# Or even
if os.system("grep 'string to find' 'my_file.txt'") != 0:
    # Nothing found or some error occurred
```

Either way, all output goes to stdout and error messages to stderr, which are generally the user's terminal. If you just want to know if the pattern matches somewhere in the file, use `grep -q`, which suppresses errors and output and stops at the first match (which can be quite a lot faster if there are large files and the pattern usually occurs near the beginning.) (Shell errors will still be reported on stderr, though.)

If you need to do a better analysis of error conditions (bad regex, file not found, bad shell command format, etc.), then you'll probably want to use an interface which can capture stderr, such as `subprocess.Popen`.